# Why my regex with r'string' matches but not 'string' using Python?

Tags: python, regex

The way regex works in Python is so intensely puzzling that it makes me more furious with each passing second. Here's my problem:

I understand that this gives a result:

```
re.search(r'\bmi\b', 'grand rapids, mi 49505)
```

while this doesn't:

```
re.search('\bmi\b', 'grand rapids, mi 49505)
```

And that's okay. I get that much of it. Now, I have a regular expression that's being generated like this:

```
regex = '|'.join(['\b' + str(state) + '\b' for state in states])
```

If I now do `re.search(regex, 'grand rapids, mi 49505')`, it fails for the same reason my second `search()` example fails.

My question: Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Note: The square brackets are redundant (actually, harmful: the difference between `O(n)` and `O(1)` memory consumption), use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The anwser itself**

```
regex = '|'.join([r'\b' + str(state) + r'\b' for state in states])
```

The reason behind this is that the 'r' prefix tells Python to not analyze the string you pass to it. If you don't put an 'r' before the string, Python will try to turn any char preceding by '\' into a special char, to allow you to enter break lines (\n), tabs (\t) and such easily.

When you do `'\b'`, you tell Python to create a string, analyse it, and transform '\b' into 'backspace', while when you do `r'\b'`, Python just store '\' then 'b', and this is what you want with for regex. *Always use 'r' for string used as regex patterns.*

The 'r' notation is called 'raw string', but that's misleading, as there is no such thing as a raw string in Python internals. Just think about it as a way to tell Python to avoid being too smart.

There is another notation in Python < 3.0, `u'string`', that tells Python to store the string as unicode. You can combine both: `ur"é\n"` will store "\bé" as unicode, while `u"é\n"` will store "é" then a line break.

**Some ways to improve your code:**

```
regex = '|'.join(r'\b' + str(state) + r'\b' for state in states)
```

Removed the extra `[]`. It tells Python to not store in memory the list of values you are generating. We can do it here because we don't plan to reuse the list you are creating since you use it directly in your `join()` and nowhere else.

```
regex = '|'.join(r'\b%s\b' % state for state in states)
```

This will take care of the string conversion automatically and is shorter and cleaner. When you format string in Python, think about the [% operator](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples).

If states contain a list of states zip code, then there should be stored as string, not as int. In that case, you can skip the type casting and shorten it even more:

```
regex = r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(states)
```

Eventually, you may not need regex at all. If all you care is to check if one of the zip code is in the given string, you can just use `in` (check if an item is in an iterable, like if a string is in a list):

```
matches = [s for s in states if s in 'grand rapids, mi 49505']
```

**Last word**

I understand you may be frustrated when learning a new language, but take the time to give a proper title to your question. In this website, the title should end with a question mark and give specific details about the problem.

Comment: Damn it. Wait, I could be italian!

Comment: Just a complementary word. The `[]` can be removed because `(r'\b' + str(state) + r'\b' for state in states)` itself returns a `<type 'generator'>`, which can be iterated by function `next` and accepted as an argument of ''.join(). So there is no need to first construct a list from this iterator.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is the one you used yourself in the example above: raw strings.

```
regex = '|'.join(r'\b' + str(state) + r'\b' for state in states)
```

(Note that I also removed the extra brackets, turning the list comprehension into a generator expression.)

Comment: Why the need for raw strings though?

Comment: Just `\b` in a string is interpreted as a escape sequence and produces a BELL control code (I think). When you want the (resulting) regex to include an escape sequence however, then you need to make sure that the whole sequence is included in the string. So you need to escape the backslash separetely: `\\b` which results in a `\b` within the string.

Comment: @char8705: added a reason for that in my anwser.

Comment: @poke: `\b` as a string escape is `\x08`, a BS (backspace) control code, not '\x07` one-L BEL. The escape for BEL is `\a` ... a as in "alert", IIRC. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: @John Machin: Yeah, thanks ^^ But I doubt I'll remember it for next time... (well, why should I? :P)

Answer (score 2):

The key is understanding the difference between '\b' and r'\b'. Typing these in IDLE results in this output:

```
>>> '\b'
'\x08'
>>> r'\b'
'\\b'
```

So whenever you type in a backslash in a regex, you should escape it by using raw string notation.

Comment: This is misleading. Python doesn't store r'\b' as '\\b' internally. It's IDLE and most Python shell that display it that way to give you a clue of what is inside. But you won't get the same if you do print. This is going to confuse all newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break these two strings down:

```
r'\bmi\b'
```

*Python* interprets the above string as *six* characters long (backslash, letter B, etc.). A raw string suppresses Python's translation of **\b** into a backspace.

*re* interprets the two characters **\** and **b** as a word break.

```
'\bmi\b'
```

*Python* interprets the above string as *four* characters long (backspace, letter B, etc.).
*re* now sees nothing special to interpret and looks for those literal four characters.

So the construction below is looking for backspaces, not word breaks:

```
regex = '|'.join(['\b' + str(state) + '\b' for state in states])
```

Try this (dropping `str`, state should already be a string):

```
regex = '|'.join([r'\b' + state + r'\b' for state in states])
```

The word break doesn't need to be processed in every OR expression.  Pulling it out simplifies the join:

```
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(states) + r')\b'
```

Since Pythonistas usually frown on regexes, might as well make a readable one:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'''
    (?ix) # ignore case, verbose
    \b    # word break
    (     # begin group 1
    AL|AK|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|FL|GA|
    HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MD|
    MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|
    NM|NY|NC|ND|OH|OK|OR|PA|RI|SC|
    SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY
    )     # end group 1
    \b    # word break
    ''')

m = pattern.search('Grand Rapids, MI 49505')
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Comment: "Since Pythonistas usually frown on regexes..." Interesting. How come? What would you use instead?